# Border animation from top-center to bottom-center of square with or without keyframes

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to create a border animation for my hero section, which executes on page load. It should start from the top-center of the div and finish at the bottom-center. Shown below:

[image]

This square should be transparent...so, the background image can be seen. I've tried many online solutions from CodePen and StackOverflow, but all the solutions using backgrounds on the border animation div and its child div...so the parent div's background looks like a border. So far, I was able to accomplish this but far from what I want. Here's my code:

```css
.section-hero {
  position: relative;
}
.section-hero .image-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.section-hero .image-background img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.section-hero .section-container-content {
  padding: 20px;
}
.section-hero .hero-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.section-hero .section-wrapper {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.section-hero .section-wrapper.animated-border {
  --border-width: 1px;
  --animation-speed: 3s;
  --color: #dda72e;
  border: var(--border-width) solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  animation: borderColors var(--animation-speed) steps(1) forwards;
}
.section-hero .section-wrapper.animated-border:before,
.section-hero .section-wrapper.animated-border:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
.section-hero .section-wrapper.animated-border:before {
  animation: beforeBorders var(--animation-speed) forwards ease-in-out;
}
.section-hero .section-wrapper.animated-border:after {
  animation: afterBorders var(--animation-speed) forwards ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes beforeBorders {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    left: 50%;
    bottom: auto;
    right: auto;
    width: 0;
    height: var(--border-width);
  }
  33% {
    top: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    left: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    bottom: auto;
    right: auto;
    width: calc(var(--border-width) + 50%);
    height: var(--border-width);
  }
  66% {
    top: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    left: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    bottom: auto;
    right: auto;
    width: var(--border-width);
    height: calc((var(--border-width) * 2) + 100%);
  }
  100% {
    top: auto;
    left: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    bottom: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    right: auto;
    width: calc(var(--border-width) + 50%);
    height: calc((var(--border-width) * 2) + 100%);
  }
}
@keyframes afterBorders {
  0% {
    top: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    left: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    right: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: var(--border-width);
  }
  33% {
    top: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    left: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    right: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    width: calc(var(--border-width) + 50%);
    height: var(--border-width);
  }
  66% {
    top: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    left: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    right: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    width: var(--border-width);
    height: calc((var(--border-width) * 2) + 100%);
  }
  100% {
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    bottom: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    right: calc(var(--border-width) * -1);
    width: calc(var(--border-width) + 50%);
    height: calc((var(--border-width) * 2) + 100%);
  }
}
@keyframes borderColors {
  0% {
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  33% {
    border-top-color: var(--color);
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
  66% {
    border-top-color: var(--color);
    border-right-color: var(--color);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: var(--color);
  }
  100% {
    border-top-color: var(--color);
    border-right-color: var(--color);
    border-bottom-color: var(--color);
    border-left-color: var(--color);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="section-hero">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section-container-content">
            <div class="image-background">
                <img class="image-cover" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300">
            </div>
            <div class="section-wrapper animated-border">
                <div class="hero-wrapper">
                    <div class="section-intro">
                        <h1 class="section-title">title</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

As seen in the snippet, border animation is jumping. How to achieve the desired result? Any suggestions/help will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: with or without border-radius ?

Comment: @temaniafif a little border radius of around 5px will do. It works without border radius too if we have a solution.